# I have a problem using javaFX, errormessage: java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.base not found

Tags: java, javafx

I have added the correct libraries and added the vm-options, yet it still gives me this error message and a headache. My VM-options are as such: --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX}\lib --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.web

I have tried searching other peoples post but it is fixed for them after adding the vm-option.... please help!

Answer (score 0):

What is the java vm you are using?
FX was removed from the standard java distribution.
It is now supported by https://openjfx.io

You can either download the OpenJavaFx to your VM or use a VM with embedded FX like Zulu: https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk-fx

I personally recommend using sdkman! to manage your vms: https://sdkman.io

Good luck!

Comment: I am using java 11 and have installed the javaFX sdk. Added the javafx path to PATH_TO_FX and imported the library to my libraries within the project. Also did the vm options as shown above and imported a couple javafx.scene etc. etc. in my syntax.

Comment: what is the error message exactly? Please edit your post and include more details about the error message and your environment.